# Selenium Python coding to select dropdown : getting error SeleAttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'tag_name'

Tags: python, selenium, select, dropdown

Code:

```html
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
driver.get("http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmlselect.php")
time.sleep(5)
element= driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/div[4]/select')
sel= Select(element)
sel.select_by_value("CO")
time.sleep(5)
print('Done')
```

**Error message**
    if webelement.tag_name.lower() != "select":
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'tag_name'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please find below solution to resolve your problem. Xpath is wrong in your solution

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
driver.get("http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmlselect.php")
time.sleep(5)

select =Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[4]//select[1]"))
select.select_by_index(1)


print('Done')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using find_elements_by_xpath which returns a list, try using find_element_by_xpath instead. And also you didn't include the part of the code where the error happens.